# PowerShell scriptblock syntax is giving me trouble

Tags: windows, powershell, console

I'm trying to execute a script block using powershell in the console, and I can't quite get the syntax working like I want.  I need another set of eyes, because I've been staring at this for a long time.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
C:\Users\Administrator.MAUL>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Inputformat None -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "&  {'C:\Users\Administrator.MAUL\Scripts\InstallTransportAgent.ps1' -ExchangeDir 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14' -AgentDir 'C:\Users\Administrator.MAUL\Project\TransportAgent\bin\x64\Debug' }"
```

The result:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:126
+ &  {'C:\Users\Administrator.MAUL\InstallTransportAgent.ps1' - <<<< ExchangeDir 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14' -AgentDir 'C:\Users\Administrator.MAUL\Project\TransportAgent\bin\x64\Debug' }
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the command (I cannot test this):

```
"& 'C:\Users\Administrator.MAUL\Scripts\InstallTransportAgent.ps1' -ExchangeDir 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14' -AgentDir 'C:\Users\Administrator.MAUL\Project\TransportAgent\bin\x64\Debug'"
```

(script block is not needed, actually)

Comment: The script block is needed, as best I can tell, because this command is being executed in a Windows Server 2008 console, not in powershell.

Comment: Script block is not needed, as best as I can tell :), neither for the .ps1 script (as in the example) nor for an executable file. It is the PowerShell that executes the -Command argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out: inside the script block, I need to also include a second call operator, like this:

```
... -Command "& {&'path/to/exe' ...}"
```